# oAuth with Custom Login screen in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, oauth

Is there a way in which i can use oAuth but provide my own Custom Login screen and not the web view ??
Any light on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think it is not possible as i had also tried for myspace , twitter to show login form within app such as with out going to web browser.

Answer (score 0):

That would completely defeat the point of OAuth -- where you only ever authenticate against the original site -- so no, it's not possible. Some sites have an alternative to OAuth such as xAuth.